# Стоит ли начинать изучение ASP.NET с WebForms

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-webforms

Начал изучать ASP.NET, купил книжку Адама Фримена по MVC5. После прочтения трети книги никакого понимания что и как не прибавилось. Вопрос, может стоит начать изучение с WebForms? Помогут ли эти знания при изучении MVC? Или все настолько непохоже, что я просто потеряю время?

Comment: формы не сильно вам помогут в изучении ASP.NET MVC, они уходят в прошлое. Лучше сфокусироваться на MVC и это нормально что много не понятно. Если вы никогда не сталкивались с этими технологиями понадобится немного больше времени, чем то что нужно на прочтение одной книги Фримена.

Comment: @koks_rs видимо нужно поискать автора попроще. Кто пишет проще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebForms и MVC - два *совершенно разных* подхода к разработке приложений.

Опыт разработки под WebForms ничем не облегчит вам изучение MVC.

Более того, опыт разработки под WebForms не облегчит вам изучение вообще ни одной из современных платформ - из-за очень специфической модели для представления страниц как долгоживущих объектов. Которая, кстати, и привела к отказу от этой технологии в сторону MVC.

Не стоит тратить на них время.